# ggplot annotate text with less than symbols and subscripts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a plot with ggplot that has annotated text. The text should have 3 letters with numeric subscripts next to them, separated by less-than/greater-than symbols and single whitespaces. I've tried 3 things:

1) if I omit the subscripts and don't use `parse = TRUE`, then the less-than symbols display correctly.

2) If I use `parse = TRUE`, add single quotes and try to use subscripts, the text displays, but I get no subscripts.

3) If I omit the single quotes and use `parse = TRUE` I get an error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0)) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y), size=0)

g + annotate("text", x=0, y=0, label = "r1 > r2 < r3", size=10) 

g + annotate("text", x=0, y=0, label = "'R[1] > R[2] < R[3]'", size=10, parse = TRUE)

g + annotate("text", x=0, y=0, label = "R[1]~>~R[2]~<~R[3]", size=10, parse = TRUE)
```

Comment: not ideal spacing, but you can try `"R[1]*' > '*R[2]*' > '*R[3]"`

Comment: removed my answer as this is a better solution

Comment: @baptiste: thanks so much, that works perfectly. The spacing is fine. If you add it as an answer i'll accept it.